# Trying to calculate the distance between 2 points

Tags: c

```
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Program Chapter 2 Modify                        */
/*                                                 */
/* This program calculates the                     */
/* distance between two points                     */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
/* Declaration and initialization of variables.*/
double x1=1, y1=5, x2=4, y2=7, side_1, side_2, distance;

/* Compute the sides of a right triangle.      */
side_1 = x2 - x1;
side_2 = y2 - y1;
distance = sqrt(side_1*side_1 + side_2*side_2);

/* Print results.                              */
printf("The distance between the two points is ""%5.2f \n", distance);

/* Exit program.                               */
return 0;
}
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

I'm trying to get it to output "The distance between the two points is 3.61" in C via Visual Studio 2010 and it isn't working. This is my first time writing a C program. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Next time, please include information about what exactly isnt working. Happy programming!

Comment: insert `system("pause");` before `return 0;`

Comment: Nice OP included desired output, but "it isn't working" does not say what happened.  What was the unexpected result?

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in this line. It should be

```
printf("The distance between the two points is %5.2f \n", distance);
```

Notice that you had two double-quotes in there.

Comment: Thanks! One more question, how come the command prompt pops up for a second then closes out when it's run? Shouldn't I be able to look at the answer then exit the prompt myself?

Comment: You can use the `getchar()` function after the prompt. This will wait for the user to press a button before the prompt closes.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason the code in the book I'm using has double quotes. That was odd to me. I decided to go with system("pause") to pause it.

Comment: Although unusual, there is nothing wrong with those two double-quotes - at least in a compliant C compiler.  It simple means the end of one string and the start of another.  String concatenation is done all the time with the macros like `PRId32` from `<stdint.h>`.  OP's problem is elsewhere.